# Problemas con el filtro de un RecycleView

Tags: android, lista, filtro

Tengo un RecycleView, al cual me gustaría implementarle un filtro. En el onquerytextchange intento llamar al metodo getFilter del adaptador pero me salta este mensaje. "Cannot resolve method 'getFilter'"
Mi código es el siguiente.

MainActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    recycle_adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
    return false;
}
```

Framento

```
    recycle_adapter= new RecycleViewAdapter(controlador.getlistaCancion_movil(), new RecycleViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(Class_Canciones clase, int position) {
            cancion_selecionada=clase;
        }
    }, R.layout.items_listview);
```

RecycleAdapter

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if(filtro==null){
        filtro=new CustomFilter();
    }
    return filtro;
}
```

Filter

```
import android.widget.Filter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import josu.start.up.mysoundlibrary.Adapters.RecycleViewAdapter;

 import static josu.start.up.mysoundlibrary.Fragmentos.fragmento_listview.recycle_adapter;

 public class CustomFilter extends Filter {
@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
    FilterResults resulst = new FilterResults();
    if(charSequence != null && charSequence.length()>0){
        //pasamos a mayusculas
        charSequence = charSequence.toString().toUpperCase();

        ArrayList<Class_Canciones> filtro = new ArrayList<Class_Canciones>();

        for(Integer i = 0; i< RecycleViewAdapter.filtro_lista.size(); i++){
            if(RecycleViewAdapter.filtro_lista.get(i).getTitulo().toUpperCase().contains(charSequence)){
                Class_Canciones d= new Class_Canciones(RecycleViewAdapter.filtro_lista.get(i).getId(),RecycleViewAdapter.filtro_lista.get(i).getTitulo(),
                        RecycleViewAdapter.filtro_lista.get(i).getArtista(),RecycleViewAdapter.filtro_lista.get(i).getAlbum(),RecycleViewAdapter.filtro_lista.get(i).getRuta());
                filtro.add(d);
            }
        }
        resulst.count= filtro.size();
        resulst.values = filtro;
    }else{
        resulst.count= RecycleViewAdapter.filtro_lista.size();
        resulst.values = RecycleViewAdapter.filtro_lista;
    }

    return resulst;
}

@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
    RecycleViewAdapter.lista= (ArrayList<Class_Canciones>) filterResults.values;
    recycle_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Este error ocurre porque la declaración del adaptador no era correcto. Una vez lo he cambiado todo funciona perfectamente.